# The Weight Paint Properties panel does not show any value in near objects, but artifacts exist

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-weights

I have become better at weight painting and know that it only works on vertices but this one has me stumped (see image). There is a persistent error that I cannot remove. The properties panel shows no influence from the left boot but it appears in the viewport.[image: this image clearly shows the deformation and properties table]

Comment: You have what looks like a single stray vert, but you have a lot of verts selected.  It is showing the weights for one vert of those selected.  Are you sure the active selection is the stray vert?  Use weight paint mode, with vertex masking enabled, to select the stray vert instead.  You can lasso select and look right there in weight paint mode.

Comment: Hi Nathan, Thank you for responding. Where do I enable vertex masking? If I just deselect vertex one by one will that expose the culprit or delete them one by one. I've not gone into this degree of detail before.

Comment: Hi Nathan. I've just managed to remove the artifact by going to edit mode and through Mesh used Clean Up, Merge By Distance. Thank you for inspiring me to find an answer.